# Number of $X$ expressible in the form $a^3 \cdot b$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A positive integer X is said to be a cube-loving number if it can be written as $(a^3) \cdot b$, for some positive integers $a$ and $b$ ($a>1$,$b \ge 1$). Given a positive integer $n$, determine the number of Cube-loving numbers less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi Bharat, maybe you can add one extra detail: where does this problem come from? Is it from an old contest?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the Cube-loving numbers are exactly those numbers divisible by $p^3$ where $p$ is a prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is the live problem of the hackerrank University Code spring https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/university-codesprint-5/challenges/cube-loving-numbers. You do not suppose to ask here. Please make your effort in the contest.